# Navigation Background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site were I have navigational links, when these links are hovered the background image changes, I have this working fine which you can see [Here](http://foley13.webfactional.com/html/template.html) The thing is I want it so when a user navigates away from the links it goes back to showing the original image when the page first loaded.

Here is my javascript :

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#mainNav a");
    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
        nodes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", this.getAttribute("title"));
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    <a href="#" title="Page 1">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#" title="Page 2">Page 2</a>
    <a href="#" title="Page 3">Page 3</a>
    <a href="#" title="Page 4">Page 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you considered the `mouseout` event?  https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Add IDs to a tags(links) then use mouseout functions as @devlincarnate said.

`$( "#{LINK_ID}" ).mouseout(function() {
  // edits div with bg image
});`

Comment: Hi, I'm not a javascript developer, how would I add a mouseout function to my script?

Comment: Thankyou, I have this now working but I cant mark your answers as answered?